# find max of second element of two dimension array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have got an array called mark which is two dimensional as below and shows student id and mark:

```
mark =   [
    [1,100],
    [1,150], 
    [1,80],
    [2,100],
    [1,300],
    [2,250]
]
```

I am going to create an array with students id and max mark as below:

```
result: [
    [1,300],
    [2,250]
]
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. Show us what you've tried, and what you're having trouble with.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Dear Oka, this is a very small part of my code and I simplified my question into it. I am looking for a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the easiest way is to use the key/value pairs of an object to create a temporary storage space while you loop over the array. Set the first element of each inner array as the object key and add it to the value if its value is greater than the value that already exists. Then just export it as an array.

```
function getResult(arr) {

    // create a temporary object for storage
    var tmp = {};

    // loop through the array elements
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {

        // set the key/values to the first and second values of
        // of the iterated array element
        var key = arr[i][0];
        var value = arr[i][1];

        // if the key doesn't exist in the object
        // set it to zero
        if (!tmp[key]) { tmp[key] = 0; }

        // if the value is greater than the current value
        // change the value of the object
        if (value > tmp[key]) { tmp[key] = value; }
    }

    // use `map` to iterate over the object keys and
    // create an array of results
    // adding + before `el` coerces the object key string
    // into an integer
    return Object.keys(tmp).map(function (el) {
      return [ +el, tmp[el] ];
    });

}

getResult(mark); // [ [1, 300], [2, 250] ]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u0u1psy1/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Cover your "mark" tab.

for each elements,

```
if(mark[i][1] > result[mark[i][0]])
    result[mark[i][0]] = mark[i][1]
```

You got your results in an object like this

```
results = {
   1: 300,
   2: 250
}
```

Comment: this result could be cover like an Array with loop like : "for (var id in results) { results[id] // done the mark for id }"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `array.sort()` function with a `custom compare function`, the maximum will then be the first element in the result:

```js
mark = [[1,100], [1,150], [1,80], [2,100], [1,300], [2,250]];

mark.sort(function(a,b){
    return b[1] - a[1];
});

console.log(mark);
```

This function will sort the array descending based on the value of the inner arrays' second item. You could change it to be ascending by changing `b[1] - a[1]` to `a[1] - b[1]`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0rr6fnez/)