# How to iterate an object and build a new one

Tags: javascript, object, nested

I am using JavaScript to iterate customers in an object which is constructed as follows:

```
[
{
    "customer": "Customer 1",
    "project": "1"
},
{
    "customer": "Customer 2",
    "project": "2"
},
{
    "customer": "Customer 2",
    "project": "3"
}
]
```

I wish to build a new object in iteration which would be constructed like this:

```
[
{
    "Customer 1": {
        "projects": "1"
    }
},
{
    "Customer 2": {
        "projects": [
            "2",
            "3"
        ]
    }
}
]
```

Any tips how this could be achieved?

Comment: Actually, you have customer objects in a list here, not customers in an object. What you want to create is also a list of objects.

Comment: [My answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30867571/1377002) might give you some clues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lookup in new array for customer and if found add project, otherwise add customer.

```
var data = [
    {
        "customer": "Customer 1",
        "project": "1"
    },
    {
        "customer": "Customer 2",
        "project": "2"
    },
    {
        "customer": "Customer 2",
        "project": "3"
    }
];
var newData = [];
data.forEach(function (el, i) {
    var customer = newData.filter(function (ell) {
        return el.customer === ell.customer;
    })[0];
    if (customer) {
        customer.projects.push(el.project);
    } else {
        newData.push({ customer: el.customer, projects: [el.project] });
    }
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newData, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This is better as a comment. Or you could expand it into a fuller answer. It's why it's being downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an intermediate object to form the inner level object. Use the iterator on that object to form the array out of it.

Please refer below for sample code.

```
var response = [
{
    "customer": "Customer 1",
    "project": "1"
},
{
    "customer": "Customer 2",
    "project": "2"
},
{
    "customer": "Customer 2",
    "project": "3"
}
];

var length = response.length,
    i = 0,
    result = {},
    j = 0,
    finalResult = [];

for(;i<length;i++){
    var eachObj = response[i];
    if(!result[response[i].customer]){
       result[response[i].customer] = [response[i].project];
    }
    else{
        result[response[i].customer].push(response[i].project);
    }
}

for(var key in result){  
    var eachObj = [];
    eachObj[key] = result[key];
    finalResult.push(eachObj);
}

console.log(finalResult);
```